# FB and IG for Embedded Assets plugin

Tags: plugin-embeddedassets

I installed the [Embedded Assets](https://plugins.craftcms.com/embeddedassets) and its working nice so far for Youtube and Twitter. I can able to save youtube video and tweets as an asset but for Facebook and Instagram, it needed to be logged in.

[image]

I would like to ask how can I save Facebook and Instagram post as an asset.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem in their github.

https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-embedded-assets/issues/150